# Insert hyperlink in Lotus Notes email manually

Tags: email, java, lotus-notes

I am trying to send an email with a link (or path of file or can be simply shared folder path), I know how to do with hotspot, but I have to do when I send the mail from Java. So, I was basically looking for the code that I have to attach in the body of the mail.

Is this possible. I am running 8.5.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you using a lotus notes java API? And how is the insert manual? Is hotspot a reference to java?

Comment: I am trying to send email which have a path(lets say : c:\testfolder\test.txt ) in the body of the mail. I am using java to send email. I want the path to work as hotspot, but how do I do it through java.

Answer (score 0):

I found this site when searching for a similar problem: [Lotus Notes creating Hotspot](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Using-Lotus-Notes-1427/Lotus-Notes-creating-Hotspot.htm).

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the Lotus Notes MIMEEntity object to create a MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions) mail with a HTML body.
See the Notes Designer Help, chapter "[Working with a MIME entity in Java classes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_WORKING_WITH_A_MIME_ENTITY_STEPS_JAVA.html)" for more information